# A class that allows for changing properties

Tags: javascript, ruby

In JavaScript, to create a class, I either create a constructor or factory to make objects.

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
}

var willy = new Person("William");
```

I can then access the property of this object as so

```
willy.name // "William"
```

I can also change it

```
willy.name = "Bill"
```

In Ruby, what is the most accepted convention (if there is such a thing) to create a class where I can access and change properties on the fly? I found this:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name  
  attr_writer :name  
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end  
end

willy = Person.new("William")
willy.name = "Bill"
```

I want to know if this is the generally accepted way to do this kind of thing in Ruby. If it isn't, then what is?

Comment: That is the right way (except that `attr_reader` and `attr_writer` can be replaced with `attr_accessor`). What made you suspect it isn't?

Comment: Use `attr_accessor` instead of attr_reader/attr_writer pair

Comment: @sawa I read some other code that used getter methods. I know that languages have different ways of doing the same things and that the communities lean toward certain conventions. In Ruby a for loop vs an each statement is an example....so I've read.  :/  Thank you

Comment: @TaoistWA Getter methods are created by `attr_reader` or `attr_accessor`. You are right: `each` is favored over `for`. But what is the alternative to getter methods?

Comment: I see. So its a short hand toward the same end.

Comment: @sawa Apparently attr_accessor is favored over explicit getter methods which I did not know. :)

Comment: @TaoistWA: attr_accessor is favored over explicit reader/writer pair. If you need only a reader, use attr_reader.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev That's what I meant but correction noted.

Answer (score 3):

If these objects are just bags of properties, then there's a shortcut called `Struct`.

```
class Person < Struct.new(:name, :last_name)
end
# or simpler
# Person = Struct.new(:name, :last_name)

willy = Person.new("William", "Darcy")
willy.name = "Bill"
willy.name # => "Bill"
willy.last_name # => "Darcy"
```

Comment: Or, even simpler, I would use a hash.

Comment: @sawa: hash doesn't look as prettily :)

Answer (score 0):

What will you use your class for? Is it only for storing data? Or for adding behavior as well?

If it's only for storing data, then use Struct:

```
Person = Struct.new(:name)
```

this is the same as typing:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name #attr_accessor is attr_reader + attr_writer
  def initialize(name=nil)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

So, to continue our example:

```
 Person = Struct.new(:name)
 a_person= Person.new
 a_person.name #nil
 a_person.name = 'Mike'
 a_person.name #=> 'Mike'
 a_second_person = Person.new('John')
 a_second_person.name #=> 'John'
 a_second_person.name = 'Maria'
 a_second_person.name #=> 'Maria'
```

If you wanted to add more methods to your simple Person Struct class, you could do something like:

```
Person = Struct.new(:name) do
  def reversed_name
    name.reverse
  end
end
a_person= Person.new('Hillary')
p a_person.reversed_name #=> "yralliH"
```

but if you already decided to add a bunch of behaviors for your class, then it's better to go with a normal declaration like with your example instead of using Struct.